# How to export a csv file after uploading a excel file and manipulating the data using post request in ajax java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is:
I am uploading a excel file first. After reading the file and manipulating the data, i need to generate a csv and export the same on click of the submit button.

Below is my html/javascript code:

```
<div>Please upload the Excel File</div>
<form method="POST" id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id = "defaultSubmit" />
</form>
```

Below is the Ajax Request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#defaultSubmit").click(function (event) {
        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
          event.preventDefault();
      //    $("#fileupload").click();

          // Get form
          var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

            // Create an FormData object 
          var data = new FormData(form);


             $.ajax({
                 url : "/uploadExcelFiles",
                 type: "POST",
                 enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                 data: data,
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 success : function(data) {
                 },
                 error : function(data) {
                 }
             });
          return false;
        });
```

Now Below is the java code:

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadExcelFiles")
    public void readExcelFile(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadedFile) {     

        File file = new File(uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
        List<EmployeeData> empData = new ArrayList<>();
        empData = blAttendanceService.readFile(file);
        TreeMap<Object, Object> map = blAttendanceService.calculateWorkingSecondsForEmployeeInDay(empData);

        List<EmployeeChartsModel> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Entry<Object, Object> ent : map.entrySet()) {
            EmployeeChartsModel ehd = new EmployeeChartsModel();
            long seconds = (long) ent.getValue();
            double dailyHoursSpent = (double)seconds/3600;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");
            System.out.println("Date::: " + sdf.format((Date)ent.getKey()) + " ::::::Hours:::: " + dailyHoursSpent);
            ehd.setEmployeeDate(sdf.format((Date)ent.getKey()));
            ehd.setDailyHoursSpent(dailyHoursSpent);
            list.add(ehd);
        }
        String filename = "DailyAttendanceRecord.csv";

        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

        try {
        StatefulBeanToCsv<EmployeeChartsModel> writer = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<EmployeeChartsModel>(response.getWriter())
                    .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                    .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
                    .withOrderedResults(false)
                    .build();

            writer.write(list);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

EmployeeChartsModel is a class for csv Model.

I am not getting any error in the code. Just the file is not exported. Also, If i read the file manually from my location and direct hit the url of this method, the file is successfully exported. But i am unable to do so through ajax post request.

Kindly suggest the changes so as to export the csv file using this ajax post request.

I am using Java, Spring Boot, Html, Javascript in my code.

Comment: you should step debug your code

Comment: I did it, but of no use. It is not throwing any error. With Ajax POST request, it is not downloading the file.